# Limit search to custom field

Tags: search

I have a custom post type bananas with a custom field _bananas_size (size is a number). Now I'd like a search field that only searches the custom field size. For example: the visitors selects value 6 and hits search. Then I want only the bananas with a size of 6 or bigger to show up as results. I've found multiple topics on how to handle a search with custom post types. However I haven't found how to limit the search to a custom post field.

What I currently have is this:

**searchform.php**

```
<form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="bananas" /> 
<select name="size">
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**search.php**

```
$type = 'bananas';
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => '_bananas_size',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_bananas_size',
            'value' => $_GET['size'],
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This returns a list of all bananas, no matter the size. How can I limit the search to the _bananas_size field?

---

**Update:**

I tried to do a var_dump like Tomás Cot suggested below but I got no output at all (even not from an `echo "<h1>Size: </h1>";`). I changed the searchform.php to:

```
<form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">

<input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search&hellip;">
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="bananas">


<input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

This resulted in the following output:

`var_dump($_GET['size']);`: NULL

`var_dump($my_query->request);`: http://pastebin.com/XYwqW2F9

**Update 2:**

It turned out that I had a typo in my code (fieldname was _bananassize, not _bananas_size). A very big thanks to @Tomás Cot for finding this! The code he posted below in the answer works great after I fixed my mistake.

Comment: Banana size should probably be a custom taxonomy, especially if you're wanting to use it as a filter. Also don't discard the search query like that ( you may as well just use `query_posts` in this case as you're doing the same thing ). Use `pre_get_posts` to modify the search query before it happens

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't think a custom taxonomy is the way to go for me in this situation since the size of the banana can be any value larger then zero. In my question I only wrote a select for quick testing, in reality it would be an input field. I don't yet completely understand the way I got to go with pre_get_posts, so I'll have to dive into that one. I take it it will be better if I made a widget and use that instead of completely discarding the search query and then use pre_get_posts to manipulate the query somehow so that it filters on _bananas_size

Comment: Or you can write code to auto-assign it a term such as 5-8 10-20 etc then use those terms to filter and fill out your drop down, you'd get free taxonomy archives for it too so you wouldn't even need to modify any queries

Comment: I understand the advantage of using an interval like that, however there might once be a situation where it's important to have exact values. For example with machinery that require a specific volume.

Comment: can you do a `var_dump($_GET);` with the original form?

Comment: @TomásCot There is no var_dump output at all when I use the original form...

Comment: You should be doing the var_dump in the seach.php file. algo, change `site_url` for `home_url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$type = 'bananas';
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'bananas',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => '_bananas_size',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_bananas_size',
            'value' => $_GET['size'],
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

You can read more about the parameters for the WP_Query [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Also, some type of data validation and sanitization is recommended.

Comment: Oops, I wasn't being paying enough attention when I wrote that part. And you're totally correct on data validation, however I'm just playing with this for now and I wanted to keep it as clean as possible. The code you suggest however doesn't return what I want. I think what TomJNowell suggests is the way to go

Comment: If you are new to Wordpress, I recommend you to go with WP_Query.  `query_posts` requires a lot of attention as well as the `per_get_posts` hook. What isn't working with this query?

Comment: This query returns all the bananas, not only the ones that have a size larger then (or equal to) `$_GET['size']`. Which I find strange.

Comment: can you do a var_dump of `var_dump($_GET['size'])` just in case, and of this: `$my_query->request`.

Then add it to the question